# Scrape HTML table text without ID or Class - JavaScript or jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, web-scraping

I have some difficulties trying to scrape som data from website HTML table. There are no ID or Class to the tag i want to retrive so i was woundering if you guys could help me with this:

**This is how the table looks (code is cutted for not taking alot of space in this post)**:

```
<table class="table table-striped table-large1">
    <thead>
<tr class="small">
    <th>No</th>
    <th>Date/Time</th>
    <th colspan="7">Indexed pages /<br>
    Processed / Skipped / Fetched /<br>
    Change (Added / Removed)</th>
    <th>Proc.time</th>
    <th>Bandwidth</th>
    <th>Broken links</th>
    <th>Images</th>
    <th>Videos</th>
    <th>RSS</th>
    <th>News</th>
</tr>
</thead>
<tbody><tr class="block1">
    <td>1</td>
    <td><a href="site/3845806/chlog/?log=8950501" title="View details">2018-06-20 01:13</a></td>
    <td>944</td>
    <td>969</td>

    <td><i><strike>25</strike></i></td>
    <td>920</td>

    <td><i style="color:#900">↓-2</i></td>
    <td><i>-</i></td>
    <td><i>-2</i></td>

    <td>0:12:44s</td>
    <td>28.82M</td>
    <td>3</td>
<td>580</td>
<td>4</td>
<td>8</td>
<td>0</td>
</tr>
<tr class="block1">
    <td>2</td>
    <td><a href="site/3845806/chlog/?log=8934464" title="View details">2018-06-17 01:14</a></td>
    <td>946</td>
    <td>968</td>

    <td><i><strike>22</strike></i></td>
    <td>919</td>

    <td></td>
    <td><i>+2</i></td>
    <td><i>-2</i></td>

    <td>0:14:05s</td>
    <td>28.89M</td>
    <td>0</td>
<td>580</td>
<td>4</td>
<td>8</td>
<td>0</td>
    </tr>
(........)
```

What i want to scrape is these 2 lines:

```
<td><a href="site/3845806/chlog/?log=8950501" title="View details">2018-06-20 01:13</a></td>
<td>944</td>
```

These are in index 2 in each , how can i get all these values?

Comment: Loop over each `tr`, then get `td:eq(1)` and `td:eq(2)` within that. If you want a more specific example, please edit the question to show what you've attempted

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Loop over all `tr` tags and use `find()` method of jquery to target the particular td element. And then clear its html using `innerHTML = "";`

```
$(".table-large1 tr").each(function() {
  if ($(this).find("td").length > 0) {
    $(this).find("td")[1].innerHTML = "";
    $(this).find("td")[2].innerHTML = "";
  }

})
```

```js
$(".table-large1 tr").each(function() {
  if ($(this).find("td").length > 0) {
    $(this).find("td")[1].innerHTML = "";
    $(this).find("td")[2].innerHTML = "";
  }

})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table class="table table-striped table-large1">
  <thead>
    <tr class="small">
      <th>No</th>
      <th>Date/Time</th>
      <th colspan="7">Indexed pages /<br> Processed / Skipped / Fetched /<br> Change (Added / Removed)</th>
      <th>Proc.time</th>
      <th>Bandwidth</th>
      <th>Broken links</th>
      <th>Images</th>
      <th>Videos</th>
      <th>RSS</th>
      <th>News</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr class="block1">
      <td>1</td>
      <td><a href="site/3845806/chlog/?log=8950501" title="View details">2018-06-20 01:13</a></td>
      <td>944</td>
      <td>969</td>

      <td><i><strike>25</strike></i></td>
      <td>920</td>

      <td><i style="color:#900">↓-2</i></td>
      <td><i>-</i></td>
      <td><i>-2</i></td>

      <td>0:12:44s</td>
      <td>28.82M</td>
      <td>3</td>
      <td>580</td>
      <td>4</td>
      <td>8</td>
      <td>0</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="block1">
      <td>2</td>
      <td><a href="site/3845806/chlog/?log=8934464" title="View details">2018-06-17 01:14</a></td>
      <td>946</td>
      <td>968</td>

      <td><i><strike>22</strike></i></td>
      <td>919</td>

      <td></td>
      <td><i>+2</i></td>
      <td><i>-2</i></td>

      <td>0:14:05s</td>
      <td>28.89M</td>
      <td>0</td>
      <td>580</td>
      <td>4</td>
      <td>8</td>
      <td>0</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```